# jQuery - Add units to offset

Tags: jquery, offset

Small problem. I have a `div id="comHere"` somewhere in the middle of the design. 
And at the top of the design, I have an `<a href="#comeHere">Click Here</a>`.

Now, when I click on the href link, it scrolls to the div using this code

`scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top`

My requirement is that, say the `div` is having a position offset of `600px` from top, when I click on the link I want the scroll to happen to `600px+100px` and not to `600px`.

Is this possible using jQuery ?

Thanks,
Dev

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top - 100
```

Comment: Thanks. I had to change it "+" to "-". Otherwise it was scrolling to 500px. I had earlier tried with 100em, 100px.